What timezone does the date in the UNTIL field of the recurrence rule represent?
According to the google documentation and the RFC5545 which is used by Google, the UNTIL date in the recurrence rule of a recurring event can be either a DATE or a DATE-TIME.
Usually a DATE-TIME in UTC format is returned, so most of the time I expect something like that:
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20241103T235959Z;BYDAY=MO
However, apparently sometimes events may contain only the DATE, and the recurrence rule looks like this:
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20241103;BYDAY=MO
I would like to know if, in such cases, the UNTIL date is in UTC or local time?
If it's the latter, does specifying the timezone field when retrieving an event make a difference? Will it return a recurrence rule with UNTIL as a local date based on a google calendar time zone, or rather based on the requested time zone?
Provided examples are anonymized. I noticed such data on a production, but for some reason I cannot really reproduce it. No matter what time zone I use in my Google Calendar, it always returns the DATE-TIME in UTC. I've received some suggestion on another forum that for all-day events the UNTIL should contain only the DATE, but I've tested this and I'm still receiving the DATE-TIME.

Interpreting Google Calendar API response default value
Whenever you are trying to create an event using an API, whether it is in UTC or local time, it will automatically convert into UTC format, and then when it reaches your Google calendar, it will be adjusted to your local timezone.
However, all the response from the API will be on UTC.
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20241103;BYDAY=MO
I have tried to reproduce it using an all-day event and got the expected result.
SAMPLE OUTPUT

If you are referring to why the startTime and endTime were formatted as Date-time UTC, it is because after you have created it using the API, it then converted to UTC (the default value type is DATE-TIME as stated in Date-Time of RFC5545) as Google server, which is 00, and after it got processed to your own Google calendar, it then converted into your local timezone. (As per my part +8:00; therefore, I got the 16:00 since the start of the 00 is 8:00.
Note: This is based on my understanding of how time value types and date time works in Google calendar recurrence
